# online bin packing and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, online-algorithms, operations-research

I am trying to optimize scheduling disk allocation in data centers. In nature it is an online bin packing problem. But, since each customer has it's own behavior or kind of workload I was wondering, if there is a room to utilize machine learning algorithms to design a better scheduler ? In other words, do you think is it possible to hire machine learning algorithms to design an online packing algorithm ?

I am new in machine learning subject and it's been a long time since I studied algorithms. Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.